# Filter based on path

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I am making a system based on various API Controllers. With a proper jwt token in place. (this token contains the user, and what customers he is having access to)
Currently the controllers needs, by convention, to check if a given user has access to the customer in question.

I am wondering if I could do this a little more elegant :) - lets say if the base url is always /api/customer//, then best solution would be to make a "something" that always checks if  is part of given users claim.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in ASP.NET Core .

To meet your requirement , firstly create authorization policy :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CustomRequire", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new CustomerRequirement()));
});
```

Register one requirement , create `CustomerRequirement.cs` :

```
public class CustomerRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public CustomerRequirement()
    {
    }
}
```

Create `CustomerHandler.cs`:

```
public class CustomerHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomerRequirement>
{
    IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = null;

    public CustomerHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                CustomerRequirement requirement)
    {

        HttpContext httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;


        var path = httpContext.Request.Path;

        //split the path to get the customer base on your path .

        var customerName = "customerFromPath";

        if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "customer"))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var customer = context.User.FindAll(c => c.Type == "customer" ).FirstOrDefault();

        if (customerName.Equals(customer.Value.ToString()))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        //TODO: Use the following if targeting a version of
        //.NET Framework older than 4.6:
        //      return Task.FromResult(0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

To use `IHttpContextAccessor`, you may need to register this in your DI setup , as follows:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Register handler in the services collection during configuration :

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomerHandler>();
```

Now your can apply policies to MVC controllers :

```
[Authorize(Policy = "CustomRequire")]
// GET api/values/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

Of course , you can also register the policy globally in you application .